# Odoo 8 development essentials

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I started to read the book Odoo development essentials and i have a problem.

i created a module. but when i add a model, It doesn't appear in the database. I've written the code by hand, copy pasted from the book, restarted the Odoo server, upgraded the app, but nothing happens. The model does not show up in the database.

This is my current code:

**init**.py

```
from . import todo_model
```

todo_model.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openerp import models, fields
class TodoTask(models.Model):
    _name = 'todo.task'
    name = fields.Char('Description', required=True)
    is_done = fields.Boolean('Done?')
    active = fields.Boolean('Active?', default=True)
```

**openerp**.py

```
{
    'name': 'To-Do Application',
    'description': 'Manage your personal task with this model.',
    "author": "AP",
    "depends": ['mail'],
    "application": "True",
}
```

So basically like i said above my app is in "Local Modules"

but there is no todo.task in Database Structure\Models

Comment: __init__.py from . import todo_model

Comment: How did you start the Odoo server....`python odoo.py xxxx` and can you paste your full folder structure?

Comment: Hi there.. i figured it out.. it took me 3 hours and it was actually typo. i missed 1 underscore when named my init file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether you have installed the module. 
There are chances that you might have installed module first and then written code of model, init and other files. So, if you have already installed it please upgrade the module again and check it would work.

Else you can also you Odoo scaffolding for developing a custom module.
Use command below for it-

python odoo.py scaffold

thanks